# Launching Transmission/Dropbox behind a XBMC desktop session

Tags: session, xbmc, headless

I am trying to get my HTPC set up just how I like it.

I have Transmission scanning Dropbox for new torrents, and XBMC handling playback.

I want to use XBMC as the Desktop session, to speed up launch. How can I make sure transmission and dropbox are both launched and functioning behind XBMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe XBMC has a transmission plugin. You could just install that and configure it from there. It will be in the addons section.

http://code.google.com/p/transmission-xbmc/

If you building and HTPC I would recommend looking into these.

Openelec

http://openelec.tv/

and

Xbmc live

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMCbuntu

Answer (score 1):

See response #6:
http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=124781

This is from XBMCubuntu, but may work for desktop sessions as well. Everything with mode +x in `/etc/xbmc/live.d/` is executed at the beginning of a session.

If that doesn't work, you can always add it somewhere else, such as in your local.rc or other file that is executed on a normal desktop at login.